# Получение типа дженерика для создания объекта

Tags: java, generics

Есть простой код:

```
package com.lampa;

import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;

public class SuperApp {
    private static abstract class People {
        public People(String name) {
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }

    private static class Man extends People {
        public Man(String name) {
            super(name);
        }
    }

    private static class Factory<T extends People> {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public T create(String name) throws Exception {
            ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = (ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
            return (T) genericSuperclass.getActualTypeArguments()[0].getClass().getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(name);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Factory<Man> factory = new Factory<>();

        Man man = factory.create("Lampa");
    }
}
```

Суть следующая: есть некий абстрактный класс `People`, от которого должны наследоваться реализации, типа класса `Man`. И есть фабрика, которая создает эти реализации `Factory<T extends People>`.

Почему я не могу получить тип дженерика вот тут `(ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()` (получаю ошибку `java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType`)? И возможно ли поменять код так, чтобы лаконично осталось:

```
Factory<Man> factory = new Factory<>();
Man man = factory.create("Lampa");
```

Comment: у вашего класса `Factory<T extends People>` нет суперкласса, потому непонятно, что вы получаете вот тут `this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()`

Comment: @tym32167 да, и в целом вопрос о том, что без явной передачи типа не заработает требуемая конструкция

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Почему я не могу получить тип дженерика вот тут (ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass() (получаю ошибку java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType)?

Это происходит потому, что у `Factory` родильский класс `Object`. Он не `generic` поэтому `Object.class` не реализует `java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType` и соответственно `Object.class` нельзя к нему привести.

То что вы хотите напрямую сделать нельзя из-за того, как работают `generic`-и.

В runtime происходит процесс `erasure` или стирания. То есть информация о типе аргумента в `Factory<Man>` никак не представлена. Тип `factory` в runtime это всегда просто `Factory` и никакой информации о параметре T мы из объекта `factory` получить не можем в принципе.

Точно так же в самом классе `Factory` в `runtime` нет вообще никакой информации о том, как он был инстанциирован с конкретным типом аргумента.

Нужно или явно передавать класс, например:

```
private static class Factory<T extends People> {
    private Class<T> clazz;
    public Factory(Class<T> clazz) {
      this.clazz = clazz;
    }
    public T create(String name) throws Exception {
        return clazz.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(name);
    }
}
```

Либо явно определять подкласс:

```
private static class Factory<T extends People> {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T create(String name) throws Exception {
        ParameterizedType genericSuperclass =
              (ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        Class<?> genericArgumentClass = (Class<?>)genericSuperclass.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        return (T) genericArgumentClass.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(name);
    }
}

private static class ManFactory extends Factory<Man> {}
```

Тогда можно сделать так и будет работать:

```
Factory<Man> factory = new ManFactory();

Man man = factory.create("Lampa");
```

Тут работает, потому что в `runtime` сохраняется информация о типе класса `ManFactory` включая то, что он унаследован от `generic`-а и какие фактические аргументы были использованы. Именно эта информация достается функцией `getGenericSuperclass` (и похожей `getGenericInterfaces`).