# Обобщения c CrudRepository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Есть 4 подобных репозитория(в пример один из них):

```
public interface ClassRoomRepository<T> extends CrudRepository<T,Long> {
List<T> findByName(String name);
}
```

Есть контроллер в котором я его использую:

```
@Autowired
private ClassRoomRepository<ClassRoom> classRoomRepository;
```

Программа не отрабатывает Spring выдает ошибку, хотя если в CrudRepository записать <ClassRoom,Long> то все отрабатывает, в документации прочитал, что он принимает T.
Почему я не могу воспользоваться дженериками в данном случае, ведь все равно произойдет стирание до Object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Причина в том, что при определении переменной информация о типе стирается, а при наследовании от обобщенного класса/интерфейса с четко заданными параметрами - нет.

Т.е. вот этой записи

```
private ClassRoomRepository<ClassRoom> classRoomRepository;
```

тип `ClassRoom` существует только на этапе компиляции, а самом байткоде остается только приведение типа.

Важно, что в runtime spring никак не может узнать, что за тип был передан в качестве аргумента обобщенному интерфейсу `ClassRoomRepository`. А spring-и нужно знать этот тип, для того чтобы знать с какой сущностью идет работа, в какую таблицу БД делать запросы, какого типа сущности создавать и т.д.

Если же у вас `ClassRoomRepository` не обобщенный тип, и при наследовании от `CrudRepository` явно задан тип сущности, то эта информация о параметре сохраняется в runtime и доступна через рефлексию. И таким образом spring может ее достать.

Почитайте больше подробностей о том как это работает в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1256637/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0/1256761#1256761) и в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/365117/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-class-%d0%b4%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0/1256752#1256752)